# HtmlUnit disable status code error exception

Tags: java, htmlunit

In HtmlUnit, how to disable throw exception when the requested page returns fail status code (like 4xx)? I need to get the status code, so if it throws an exception, I can't get the status code.

```
Page page = null;
try {
    page = webClient.getPage(requestSettings);
    System.out.println(page.getWebResponse().getStatusCode()); // it doesn't go to this line because exception is already thrown
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(page.getWebResponse().getStatusCode()); // it will fail because of NullPointerException
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

The following method seems to work only on older versions of HtmlUnit. I'm using v2.25 and the method doesn't exist.

```
webClient.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new API now has `WebClientOptions`,

you should use:

```
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
```